# Set Numbering <li> to top

Tags: html, css

Currently I have this output for my `<li>`

[image]

How can I move number `3` to top?

My expected output:

[image]

I have tried with these codes, but not success. Anyone can help me solve this problem?

```html
<ol>
  <li>Namakan kenderaan malaysia
    <br>
    <br>
    <table width="80%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>i)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>ii)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>iii)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>iv)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>Suatu hari ahmad <span style="text-decoration: underline">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> pokok besar di tepi jalan. Ahmad berlari kerana <span style="text-decoration: underline">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Ahmad
    telah diselamatkan oleh bapanya. Ahmad berasa <span style="text-decoration: underline">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;c&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table width="80%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>a)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>b)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>c)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="
    display: inline-grid;
">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
      style="max-height:400px;/* display: inline-table; */">
    </div>
    <br>ssasa
    <br>
    <table width="80%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>i)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>ii)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>iii)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>iv)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%"><b>v)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="90%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Apakah kesan jika pagar besi dicat?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Pagar itu akan berkilat</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Pagar itu tidak akan menyerap haba</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Pagar itu akan tahan lebih lama</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Pagar itu tidak akan menyerap air</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Pilih objek-objek yang boleh diletakkan dalam tong kitar semula berwarna jingga.
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Cermin tingkap, bateri, pakaian</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Gelas minuman, telefon mudah-alih, tin susu</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Botol air mineral, tin minuman, baju hujan</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Periuk tanah liat, spring, suratkhabar</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Manakah objek <strong><em>tidak</em></strong> boleh menyukat jisim?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Neraca mampatan</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Neraca tuas</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Neraca elektronik</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Jam&nbsp;matahari</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Julia mempunyai 10 m reben. Dia menggunakan 1.5 m daripada reben itu untuk membuat sekuntum bunga.
    <br>Berapakah kuntum bunga yang telah dibuatnya jika baki reben itu ialah 1 m?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>4</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>6</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>5</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>7</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Manakah antara berikut sesuai untuk mengukur panjang papan putih?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Kaki</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Depa</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Jengkal</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Hasta</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Manakah tumbuhan yang melindungi diri daripada dimakan haiwan dengan cara yang sama?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Pokok keladi, pokok tomato, pokok durian</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Pokok getah, pokok betik, pokok nangka</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Pokok mangga, pokok pisang, pokok jagung</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Pokok bunga raya, pokok bunga ros, pokok nanas</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Manakah antara berikut <strong><em>bukan</em></strong> inferens bagi manusia untuk membiak?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk memastikan kemandirian spesisnya</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk mengekalkan bilangan mereka</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk mengekalkan keseimbangan alam</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Untuk menambah bilangan mereka</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Bagaimanakah nikotin dalam asap rokok menjejaskan kesihatan manusia?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Memusnahkan sel-sel dalam paru-paru.</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Menyebabkan barah tekak dan paru-paru.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Memusnahkan sel darah merah.</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Menyebabkan lelah dan bronkitis.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Pilih tujuan penyiasatan di mana ikan diletakkan dalam tangki bertutup.
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk menunjukkan bahawa air ialah keperluan asas ikan.</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk menunjukkan bahawa ikan boleh disimpan dalam tangki bertutup.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk menunjukkan bahawa udara ialah keperluan asas ikan.</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Untuk menyiasat sama ada ikan memerlukan makanan untuk terus hidup.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
  <li>
    Mengapakah manusia purba tinggal dalam gua?
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>A)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk mendapat perlindungan daripada hujan, panas matahari, dan musuh.</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>C)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Mereka suka tinggal dalam gua.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>B)</b>
          </td>
          <td width="45%" valign="top">
            <p>Untuk bersembunyi daripada hujan dan panas matahari.</p>
          </td>
          <td width="5%" valign="top">
            <b>D)</b> 
          </td>
          <td width="45%">
            <p>Untuk mengelakkan musuh.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Please refer to my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2p2yzg9/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  li > div {
       display:inline-block; /* not inline-grid */
       vertical-align: top;
    }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dcn2mb3p/1/)

Comment: Not in the fiddle it isn't.

Comment: @Paulie_D it is at the bottom in FF just checked.

Comment: Could that be because FF doesn't support `inline-grid` yet

Comment: Now, its working..I will try all the answers before I marked which answers is the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

.. `display: block;` makes the element somewhat: 100% width and not act like an list-item so appears out of list. There are more elegant solutions.

i use the gt-selector `>` to be sure only the direct children are affected.

```css
li > img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">Whatever you say, don't do it!</li>
  <li>____</li>
  <li>____</li>
  <li>____</li>
  <li>____</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Now, its working..I will try all the answers before I marked which answers is the best. Thank you.

Comment: @Imran ask away if you have any questions, i'm not seeking for points just to help out ;)

Comment: Thanks... I will ask later if I got problem.

Comment: In HTML was ok..but in PDF still not working. I thought if HTML was OK then in PDF will be OK. 

Currently I need to change from HTML to PDF.